# Аудио плеер l Радио

Tags: html

Всем привет, знает кто нибудь как можно сделать аудио-плеер с запоминанием положения кнопки плей/пауза и чтобы при переходе на другую страницу сайта плеер не перезагружался. Заранее спасибо.

Ну и если у кого-то есть код нужного плеера, то буду благодарен если скинете*

Comment: Делай [SPA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Одностраничное_приложение)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

что бы плеер  запоминал, что играет, данный адрес он должен получать с сервера.
если хочешь что бы после перехода на другую страницу плеер играл с того момента, то можно задать autoplay.   но это будет грубо и не красиво, он будет затухать и воспроизводиться.
лучше ajax, у тебя будет меняться на странице, что тебе надо, а плеер останется играть